# Trying to get property 'TransactionStatus' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am hitting a url in php laravel using curl

on my local machine i have php version 8.1.10 and the result is correct. The code i am executing is

```
$url = "some url";

$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);

$result = json_decode($jsonData);
echo $jsonData . "<br>";

if ($result->TransactionStatus == "Paid") {
    echo "<br>" . $result->TransactionStatus;
}
```

but the same code is not executing on server where php version is 7.2.34

It is giving error "Trying to get property on non object"

How i can solve this ?

Comment: debug it, check if json_decode returns an object

Comment: Your error is pretty self-explanitory; `$result` is not an Object, so `(not an object)->TransactionStatus` is not valid. It might be an Array (`$result['TransactionStatus']`), or it could be `null`, etc., but you need to handle this.

Comment: If there is no parsing error then json_decode($jsonData, false) should behave same in any php version. This means we want json object as PHP object.

Comment: Try gettype($result); Check if the output is an object.

Comment: Whenever you decode a json it becomes an array and you just have to use it like this `$result['TransactionStatus']` to acces the value.

Comment: For better understanding use [Laravel HTTP Client.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client)

Comment: As well you're using two `json_decode` `$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));` and 

`$result = json_decode($jsonData);`

Answer (score 0):

You double decode, remove one:

```
//...
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);

if ($result->TransactionStatus == "Paid") {
    echo "<br>" . $result->TransactionStatus;
}
```

Comment: it is working with double decode not single decode